# Store image url in xml and include them in ASPX page C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a ASPX page where I use many images and also same image many times. So I thought of storing the images in xml and then using the images. I am new to xml. Below is the xml part. How do I call the images from xml to my ASPX page? Any ideas or link will be helpful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImagesXml>
   <Ad>
     <ImageUrl>~/Images/image1.jpg</ImageUrl>
     <AlternateText>Img1</AlternateText>
   </Ad>
   <Ad>
     <ImageUrl>~/Images/image2.png</ImageUrl>
     <AlternateText>img2</AlternateText>
   </Ad>
</ImagesXml>
```

Below is my ASPX page where I am using the image url in div.

```
<body id="bdy">
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="invoice" runat="server" style="background: url('Images/image1.jpg');">

      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ForeColor="Black"></asp:TextBox>

      <center>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Send Mail" OnClick = "Button1_Click" />
      </center>

    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: @middelpat please avoid changing code in questions; in this case it might not do any harm but it's very risky as you might edit the actual problem out of the question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard understood, but in this case it was barely readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you only need to do something with the strings retrieved in the loop

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("path to xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> images = xelement.Elements();    

foreach (var ad in images)
{
   string imagePath = ad.Element("ImageUrl").Value;
   string imageAlt = ad.Element("AlternateText").Value;
}
```

Comment: The path needs to be a virtual path, not a physical one

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to XML to iterate your XML document and get node values on Page_Load event and set ImageUrl programmatically.

Here's example of: [LINQ to XML usage](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=564)